# Switch places of array elements - php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with two elements:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 'test1'
  [1] => 'test2'
)
```

I want

> test1

to be second element in the array and

> test2

to be the first one.
How can I easily switch their places ?

Comment: [Learn to use documentation. As a programmer, you're gonna need it.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$input  = array("test1","test2");
print_r($input);
Array
(
  [0] => 'test1'
  [1] => 'test2'
)
print_r(array_reverse($input));
Array
(
  [0] => 'test2'
  [1] => 'test1'
)
```

take a look here [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Answer (score 0):

In this -simple- case, you could use rsort($string) on your array variable:

```
<?php
    $a = [
        0 => 'test1',
        1 => 'test2'
    ];

rsort($a);
```

this reverse sorts your array values (switches places) while leaving the keys the same.